# Is there is any except validation with unique number in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

Can someone help me out to find out how to validate unique emails with some emails that are exceptional.
Here is and example:

1. we have two emails:

- `[xxx@xxxx.com, yyyy@yyy.com]`

2. Laravel provide us validation rule:

'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',

so when we register in our web app, these two emails should be ignore while searching for unique user's email in users table.

Thank you in Advance!

I have tried this but it didn't help:

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,[xxx@xxxx.com, yyyy@yyy.com]',
```

and

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email.'[xxx@xxxx.com, yyyy@yyy.com]',
```

But didn't get any results.

Answer (score 2):

use laravel [custom unique rule](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique).You may specify additional query conditions by customizing the query using the where method.

```
'email' =>[
            'required',
            'email',
            Rule::unique('users')->where(fn($query) => $query->whereNotIn('email', ['xxx@xxxx.com', 'yyyy@yyy.com']))
         ]
```